# Bug with GlobalScope in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, global-scope

When I try ti use global scope in my model:

```
    protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new PostScope(Post::TYPE_VIDEO));
    static::addGlobalScope('video', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->join('video_posts', 'post_id', '=', 'id');
    });
}
```

It doesn't work, because somewhere Laravel process double-call function `join()`.
Anybody encountered with it? How fix it?

Comment: you should try to avoid using the global scope, it will make maintaining the code harder later on.

Comment: You sure you have implemented as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#global-scopes)

Comment: @ThomasMoors i have two class: post and videopost. Videpost have all fields that post and one additional. Create new class for one field - stupidly.

Comment: @RahulMeshram when I redefine join:     public function join($table, $first, $operator = null, $second = null, $type = 'inner', $where = false, $name = null)
    {
        if ($this->originalQuery->getQuery()->joins) {
            return $this->originalQuery;
        }
        return $this->originalQuery->join($table, $first, $operator, $second, $type, $where);
    } - all works good.

Comment: there is `inheritance` (extending the class) and `traits` that would make the code cleaner

Comment: @ThomasMoors I have class basepost and two extended classes Post and Videpost. And I use global scope to get videpost with fields which contains in post model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class 'video' I would recommend to add an Eloquent relation between your two classes using hasMany / belongsTo and just grab it using

```
static::addGlobalScope('video', function ($builder) {
    $builder->with('video');
});
```

Comment: And use relation?

Comment: @gidiberat

public function videos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
}

[laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)